# Count the percentage of character fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to count the percentage of specified field data.
this is my Restful API:

**Restful API:**

```
GET _search
{
"_source": {
"includes": [ "FIRST_SWITCHED","LAST_SWITCHED","IPV4_DST_ADDR","L4_DST_PORT","IPV4_SRC_ADDR","L7_PROTO_NAME","IN_BYTES","IN_PKTS","OUT_BYTES","OUT_PKTS"]
},
"from" : 0, "size" : 10000,
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
    "match" : { "_index" : "logstash-2017.12.22" }
},
{
    "match_phrase":{"IPV4_SRC_ADDR":"192.168.0.159"}
},

{
  "range" : {
    "LAST_SWITCHED" : {
        "gte" : 1513683600
    }
    }
}

]
}
},
"aggs": {
"IN_PKTS": {
"sum": {
  "field": "IN_PKTS"
}
},
"IN_BYTES": {
"sum": {
  "field": "IN_BYTES"
}
},
"OUT_BYTES": {
"sum": {
  "field": "OUT_BYTES"
}
},
"OUT_PKTS": {
"sum": {
  "field": "OUT_PKTS"
}
},
"percent":{
"significant_terms" : {
        "field" : "L7_PROTO_NAME",
        "percentage":{}
    }},
"protocol" : {
     "terms" : {
         "field" : "PROTOCOL",
         "include" : ["17", "6"]      
        }
},
"Using_port_count" : {                 
    "cardinality" : {
        "field" : "L4_SRC_PORT"
    }
}
}
}
```

but there's some errors.
this is error messages:

**error messages:**

"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [L7_PROTO_NAME] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I find the answer!

just add .keyword at here then it can run!

"field" : "L7_PROTO_NAME.keyword"